# How to detect web based popup such as the one Google Play store is using with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

Example: 
Go to [PlayStore App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca)
Look for Permissions and click the link (View details)
Web based (Javascript activate) popup.

How to detect it?
Since this is not ordinary web based or window pop up, it doesn't detect at all.

```
PContent = driver.switchTo().activeElement().findElement(By.className("model-dialog"));
location = PContent.findElement(By.xpath("//bucket-description[text(),'precise location (GPS and network-based]")).getText();
System.out.println(location);
```

If you know how to detect it by Selenium webdriver, please help!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am getting  no such element with the above code.

Comment: There's no need to comment on your own post unless someone commented or referred you.You can add your problems into the post by editing it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idk how your code executed.It is full of bugs

1.There is no such class as `model-dialog` it is `modal-dialog`.Please copy paste from html or cross check the value at-least once.

2.`By.xpath("//bucket-description[text(),'precise location (GPS and network-based]")`.Is this really an Xpath.Read about [xpath](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/xpath-tutorial-for-selenium) then start creating once

3.That is not even a popup.It's normal Element that's hidden inside the DOM.Read about [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) and [ExpectedConditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) and see how to check for visibility of element

4.Why do you want to find an element by it's text and printing it's text. It doesn't make any sense

Well here's the full code for your Reference.It works prefectly

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca");

    WebElement permission = driver.findElement(By.className("id-view-permissions-details"));
    permission.click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement modalPopup = driver.findElement(By.className("modal-dialog"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(modalPopup));

    String xpath = "//ul[@class='bucket-description']//li[text()='precise location (GPS and network-based)']";
    WebElement whatTheHeck = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    System.out.println(whatTheHeck.getText());

    driver.quit();
```

Comment: Madhan, thank you. For the first line of code, I used my imagination because I tried all of the possible findElement combination with By, and it didn't work. Well, I appreciate your comments! I will improve my Selenium skill step by step. :)